# Java Path2D performance issue

Tags: java, graphics2d, zooming, clipping, path-2d

I have a program that utilizes Path2D.Float to draw a vector object (a large fractal design).  My code allows zooming and panning.  I have an axis object that has methods to convert world coordinates (pairs of doubles) to display coordinates (pairs of floats) based on the current scaling settings (stored in the axis object).

Anyways, the vector graphic is large and detailed and contains many line segments in world coordinates.  Each time the user zooms or pans, new Path2D objects are created and rendered to the screen.

Everything is perfectly smooth when zoomed out.  The problem occurs when I zoom in to a certain depth.  Apparently the Path2D lines get very long and this slows down their rendering (even though the vast majority is outside the viewing area!).  It's not my conversion algorithms consuming resources.  I profiled it and it's definitely the Java graphics drawing algorithm that's slowing down due to the size of the lines in comparison to the small clipping region.

I was hoping there was a way to get Java to deal with the clipping of large lines automatically.  I do call setClip() from the graphics object before drawing.  I don't see what's taking so much time.  Is there something problematic/inefficient about the clipping algorithm when lines are long in comparison the clipping rectangle?  I don't think I'm zooming so far that my conversion from world coordinates to display coordinates is causing overflow.  I'll have to check for this.  If that's the case I'll try using Path2D.double instead.

Anyways, any help appreciated.  I'm sure I'll eventually figure this out but I hope someone that's encountered the same problem can give me a pointer so it doesn't take so long to figure out.

Comment: Rather then regenerating the Shape2D vectors each time, you could simple request a scaled instance instead, you could also look at the clipping rectangle of the Graphics2D been used to paint the view and determine if the given shape intersects it, if it doesn't, don't even trying to paint it

Answer (score 1):

I've not used paths when zooming, but I have used them for drawing some very complex shapes with textures & gradients etc. Some issues I had were:

In my experience, I had to avoid creating new Path2D objects on a per frame basis because of performance issues, not just for their recreation execution, but because it caused a lot of garbage collection with generating & then dropping so many so quickly, which slowed things down. If your shape doesn't change, cache the generated path.

Avoid clipping with paths - where possible stick to rectangles - paths seem to give rough edges on curves and are more costly to use.

Even when clipping to smaller regions, simply asking to draw large regions could slow things down. Consider when the user zooms in to tessellate your shape, i.e. the shape is only as big as your viewport. Perhaps as you say maybe there is an issue with the clip function when dealing with large volume areas, so tessellation might help here.